# How this java program handles a StackOverFlow error and continues to normal flow of execution

Tags: java, exception

In the following code, the methods `A()` and `B()` are recursively calling each other which causes the `StackOverFlow` error. After catching this error how does the program continue to its normal flow of executions as the stack is already overflowed and methods `C()->D()->E()` needs to be put in the calling stack.

```
package staticTryOuts;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
        A();
       }catch(Error e) {
           System.out.println(e);
       }
        System.out.println("Hello");
        C();

    }

    static void A() {
        System.out.println("Hello from A");

        B();
    }
    static void B() {
        System.out.println("Hello from B");

        A();
    }
    static void C() {
        System.out.println("Hello World from c.");
        D();
    }
    static void D() {
        System.out.println("Hello world from D");
        E();
    }
    static void E() {
        System.out.println("Hello world from E");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception being thrown means that it propagates back up the stack, unwinding and clearing stack frames as it goes. By the time the exception makes it back to the `catch` block at the very top, the stack is basically empty again and has space for the additional stack frames of the method invocations for `C`, `D` and `E`.